# Safely inject html with attribute styles

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible to inject html with attribute styles, but without script tags?

With Angulars DomSanitizer I can call bypassSecurityTrustHtml, which does give me inline styles, but it doesn't prevent scripts from being injected.

If I simply inject the html as a string using [innerHtml], the inline styles are removed.

What I would like is for e.g. `<script>alert("0wned")</script> <div style="background-color: blue;></div>`

To be parsed as: `<div style="background-color: blue;></div>`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could provide your element with CSS class, if that possible for you

Comment: Yes, but this is for a CMS setup. Adding classes instead of using styling attributes moves the styling responsibility away from the CMS system.